# CentOS OpenVZ kernel panic when mounting ext4 truecrypt volume in nokernelcrypto mode

Tags: centos, openvz, ext4, truecrypt, kernel-panic

I am experiencing kernel panic when trying to mount a ext4 filesystem which itself resides on a truecrypt volume mounted using `-m nokernelcrypto` option.

The system is CentOS 6.3, OpenVZ Kernel 2.6.32-042stab074.10
The disk is a virtual disk (a truecrypt volume mounted with `--filesystem=none`), and the actual command triggering kernel panic is:

```
mount -o loop -t ext4 /tmp/.truecrypt_aux_mnt2/volume /mnt/storage
```

Note that:

1. It mounts fine in read-only mode, i. e. using `-m ro`
2. It also mounts perfectly fine if I boot in "normal" kernel (non-OpenVZ), which is 2.6.32-279.22.1.el6.x86_64
3. Again, it mounts perfectly fine when not using `-m nokernelcrypto` (either kernel)
4. I have to use `-m nokernelcrypto` because a 3TB disk that I have can only be mounted using that option — otherwise truecrypt refuses to mount saying "Kernel cryptographic service test failed" and suggests to upgrade kernel to 2.6.33. Not using `-m nokernelcrypto` goes OK with 2TB disks, but not with 3TB
5. The panic message features "Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception" and "kernel BUG at fs/fuse/file.c:1110!"
6. I did not have this problem when I was using Debian OpenVZ — was able to mount the 3TB using `-m nokernelcrypto` easily

I am just not sure where exactly the problem is: CentOS, OpenVZ, fuse library or the non-kernel decryption. Any clues will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem using Proxmox (see pve.proxmox.com, it's a Debian derivative). I have an ext4 file system disk image residing on a glusterfs share (which is fuse-based). As soon as I mount the disk image, I get the message about the kernel bug at fs/fuse/file.c:1110.

This all worked fine with pve-kernel-2.6.32-11-pve. I ran into the problem after upgrading the kernel to pve-kernel-2.6.32-19-pve.

So I guess the problem might occur whenever we mount a disk images that is hosted on a fuse-based file system on a recent (whatever that means) 2.6.32 kernel.